# phpBB3 - dont send activation email for certain mail services

Tags: php, email, forum, phpbb3, activation

I using **phpBB 3.0.12** and encountered with issue: 
some mail services like mail ru recognising activation emails from my from like spam messages and return them with **550 error**

> Oct 27 10:37:02 26sp postfix/smtp[31754]: 33347587974:
>   to=, orig_to=,
>   relay=mxs.mail.ru[217.69.139.150]:25, delay=2.5,
>   delays=0.01/0/0.08/2.4, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host
>   mxs.mail.ru[217.69.139.150] said: **550 spam message** rejected.
>   Please visit
>   http://help.mail.ru/notspam-support/id?c=Jdo_XLgUDbBjA8QmVnqeZQShDEMZPvTFdwpE_P3-ufG-37333wCzdKLWRJxdUdKdCgAAAPSVAAAAriEj
>   or  report details to abuse@corp.mail.ru. Error code:
>   5C3FDA25B00D14B826C40363659E7A56430CA104C5F43E19FC440A77F1B9FEFDF7BDDFBE74B300DF9C44D6A29DD2515D.
>   ID: 0000000A000095F42321AE00. (in reply to end of DATA command))

**550 error** means that users marked as spam mailings from forum and mail.ru categorized any mailings as spam. I already send request to support remove forum from spam lists but any email  notifications sended by forum doesnt eaven get to emails in mail.ru.

**Question:** i want write something like don't send email activation if user entered ****@mail.ru in registration. But im not familiar with phpBB.
can someone help me where find function for sending activation emails.

I'll be very appreciate for any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific software package; the poster should be looking for help on that package's support boards.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT! Before making any changes, make sure you have a back up just in case things go wrong.

Using FTP download from your site this file - `language/xx/ucp.php` (where xx is the language code, eg. for English it is `en`)

Open it in a proper text editor that is capable of saving files as `UTF8 without BOM` and NOT a word processor or Notepad as these can cause problems.

I'll give you the example using the English version as thats what I use on my site...

Look for:
`'UCP_ADMIN_ACTIVATE'       => 'Please note that you will need to enter a valid e-mail address before your account is activated. The administrator will review your account and if approved you will receive an e-mail at the address you specified.',`

and:
`'UCP_EMAIL_ACTIVATE'       => 'Please note that you will need to enter a valid e-mail address before your account is activated. You will receive an e-mail at the address you provide that contains an account activation link.',`

You can change the message in these two lines to suit your needs. Once done, save and upload back to your server using FTP.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my ucp.php already in UTF8 withhout BOM encoding. Issue in mail.ru, caused by users marked my mailings "as spam". I think solution is in using some special services for mailings.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, saving that format is not a solution to the problem, just to prevent any problems by using wrong software. My answer won't prevent .ru domains from being used, but you can edit the wording in that file to explain to people that they won't get the activation mail if they do.